# Why is only one of my event handlers fired?

Tags: c#, aforge

I would like to simultaneously record the video from two webcams. I am using the Aforge.Video.DirectShow package to capture each frame from the webcames. 
I started with the example shown on their website and just added a second camera.

But the problem I have is that only one of the event handler for handling new frames is fired. In the example code below it is _NewFrameHandler2.

I have the feeling that I am missing something obvious here...

```
public class Camera
{
    private VideoCaptureDevice objCamera1;
    private VideoCaptureDevice objCamera2;

    public void Start()
    {
        FilterInfoCollection objVideoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        objCamera1 = new VideoCaptureDevice(objVideoDevices[0].MonikerString);
        objCamera2 = new VideoCaptureDevice(objVideoDevices[1].MonikerString);

        objCamera1.VideoResolution = objCamera1.VideoCapabilities[objCamera1.VideoCapabilities.Count() - 1];
        objCamera2.VideoResolution = objCamera2.VideoCapabilities[objCamera2.VideoCapabilities.Count() - 1];


        objCamera1.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(_NewFrameHandler1);
        objCamera2.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(_NewFrameHandler2);

        objCamera1.Start();
        objCamera2.Start();   
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        objCamera1.Stop();
        objCamera2.Stop();
    }


    private void _NewFrameHandler1(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        Bitmap objFrame = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame;
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }

    private void _NewFrameHandler2(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        Bitmap objFrame = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame;
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to look into TPL / multitasking.  It could be a threading issue.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Kixoka I experimented a bit more and I found that the objCamerax.Start() function determines which event handler is being executed. The last one that is started is the one is actually running. So it seems to be a problem with the Aforge package maybe. I had a look into the Start() function and all they do in there is start a new thread that then reads the frames from the camera.

Comment: FYI, AForge is no longer maintained, and has been absorbed into the Accord project.  It's basically a drop-in replacement (though of course the namespaces changed).

Comment: Thanks for the input Amy, I have migrated it to Accord!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out. 
I added a 500 ms delay in between calling the .Start() function on the camera objects.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
```

Now it works.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to close it. Well, actually it is not really closed but people see that it has been answered.